# Cracks in basement and garage floors

Tags: basement

I'm I home owner and hope someone can help me because I've read so much conflicting information and don't know who else to turn to.  I've called General Contractors who can't seem to fit me into a schedule, a local ASHI certified home inspector who has not returned my call and a Structural Engineer Inspector who didn't seem to care about my problem but did say running the water from an interior drain system to daylight was better than using a sump pump.

I have a walk out basement with an attached garage.

I have vertical and stair stepping cracks on my cement blocks which are narrow, about hairline size or slightly wider..  I also have cracks in my basement and garage floors.

I had used a sealer on half of the block walls in 2007 as they had some efflorescence on them (company applied this for me).  The others I didn't use the sealant on because they had drywall on them.

I had a lot of water come into the basement and garage at the end of Feb 2015 due to all of the rain, ice and snow we had that was referred to as an ice damn (I live in Tennesee). I have lived here for 24 years and this is the first time it ever happened. I did not have a roof leak.  I had my driveway regraded.  I ended up having mold due to the flood and when the drywall was removed for Mold remediarion, a section of the wall not sealed with sealant showed signs there had been water intrusion.  I did not have a dehumidifier at that time but have a large capacity one now.

A structural repair company came out and said the cracks were due to hydrostatic pressure from the water in my soil.

They feel it is not necessary to fill the cracks since they can put in an interior drainage system that should take care of the water coming up through the floor and the narrow cracks in my concrete block to not worsen (but no guarantee on the wall) and their warranty states it covers water on my entire basement floor (and not just at the foundation wall and cove joint where they perform their work).  The drainage tile pipe would sit next to the footer. I was told the interior drainage system should help both my concrete block cracks and basement cracks from getting worse.

I was also told as part of their system they would install heavy duty plastic type drains on the inside of my garage doors just across the garage door section and just across the basement door section and this would allow water that may come back into my house to drain into the system.

As to the wall with evidence of water intrusion. they will put up a
Poly board - Plastex panels across the entire perimeter of my basement going up the entire block walls and down into the drainage system.  It is made of plastic.

In addition, due to the slope of my side and back yard, they will drain the system outside with 4" pvc pipe extending over 40 ft draining into a catch basin instead of using a sump pump.

My questions:
Should the floor cracks be sealed and if so with what product?  The widths vary and right now only one in the garage can be felt uneven when rubbing a shoe across it.  It is a small length but the running crack itself is longer.

The company's warranty does NOT cover coverings such as drywall or items that can be a food source for mold.

With that being a concern, should I ask them not to install those grates on the inside of the garage and basement doors in the event the drains cannot keep up with the amount of water coming in and possibly causing an over flow which would damage and possibly cause mold due to the new drywall I need to put up to enclose my garage?  I would like to drywall the rest of the area that was taken down from the mold remediation as well.

Do you think having the poly board properly installed on the concrete block (glued and plastic fasteners installed except at the area that goes into the system as it would curve right above the drain tile to allow water to run down into it to keep any water intrusion out (with the drainage and mold not being caused since the poly board is plastic)?  Is this sufficient?

Any professional help will be greatly appreciated.
Kim